# Swift 3: Custom Cell not displaying data

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

Im receiving a JSON array from `php` and trying to passing data to table view. However, my `tableview` does not display the data.

```
class test1ViewController: UIViewController  , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return TableData.count

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! testTableViewCell

    cell.mylabel1.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

 func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }

        print(data!)
        self.extract_json(data!)


    })

    task.resume()

}

func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{


    let json: Any?

    do
    {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
      //  print(json!)

    }
    catch
    {
        return
    }

    guard let data_list = json as? NSArray  else
    {
        return


    }

    if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
    {
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
        {
            if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
            {

                if let name = country_obj["name"] as? String
                {
                    if let age = country_obj["age"] as? String
                    {
                        TableData.append(name + age)




                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }




}
```

When the array gives initial values like 
animals = `["hinno", "ali", "khalil"]`,
the values appear to custom cell, but when i take the data from a server and do the json conversion, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reload Data of the collection or tableView doesn't work use that in Dispatch code like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         yourTableViewName.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

tableview.reloadData() any time you make changes to the array.

Comment: Thank you so much the data finally appeared